# Can i have animation on LaunchScreen in IOS Project?

Tags: ios, uiview, launchimage

As you know, in IOS7.0+, LaunchScreen can be replaced with a `UIView`. But if i want to have an animation on the UIView, I cannot figure out how much time i have to execute the animation on this `UIView` cause i don't know how much time it takes to load my rootViewController.

Or i can only have a still frame on the LaunchScreen `UIView` and execute the animation on my rootViewController?

Do you guys have any experience on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XIB file for Launch was implemented by Apple not for animation or something like this. It was implemented for supporting multiple devices without headache. 
So, as before, you can't add animation into Splash Screen.
Nevertheless, as before, you can add animation right after Splash.

Also, you can read this article - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html